# How to find out why my iPhone uploaded so much data?

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi, data-transfer

All the devices on my WiFi network have a pretty normal download/upload rate (mostly like 90/10).

My iPhone 12 mini is a pretty big exception to this. It has a nearly 50/50 upload download rate. The following image shows its data consumption on WiFi at home in the last 30 days.

[image]

I use this phone mostly to just browse the web, watch videos, etc. Nothing unusual. I do not upload to social media at all. I may send a few photos and short videos (maybe like 20 seconds) to friends occasionally.

I do *not* upload a lot of photos or videos with it as both my iCloud and Google Drive storage have been full for a while, so I do not believe any backup services are backing up this amount of data. Plus, the videos and photos I took for the last 30 days are probably 4 GB max.

I do not do a lot of video calling. Certainly not 26 GB worth.

I can not think of any other activity I do on this phone that would cause it to upload 26 GB in a month.

Is there any way I can find out what exactly is causing this? I believe there is a "data used" per app view, but it does not isolate uploads, does it?

Is this common for iPhones? I am worried that I have an app with spyware on it or something like that, that may be constantly sending some data somewhere, or something like that. I know that iOS is incredibly sandboxed and that the App Store is very strict, but you never know.